# Create new data stream inside another

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two data types.

```
type1 and type2
```

And I have a data stream of `type1`.

```
DataStream<type1> stream1 =...
```

Inside `stream1` I want to create objects of `type2` and I want to collect both - objects of `type1` and `type2`.

Is it possible to have one input type and two output types with one data stream? Or is it possible to create a new data stream (`DataStream<type2> stream2`) inside of `stream1`?

Or is there any other way to collect data of two different types evaluated from one type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a wrapper type first and split-and-select your stream later on. For the wrapper, only one member would be *not-null*;

```java
class TypeWrapper {
    // keeping this short for brevity
    public TypeA firstType;
    public TypeB secondType;
}
```

Split and select:

```java
DataStream<TypeWrapper> stream1 = ...

DataStream<TypeA> streamA = stream1.filter(new FilterFunction<TypeWrapper>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(TypeWrapper value) throws Exception {
        return value.firstType != null;
    }
})
.map(new MapFunction<TypeWrapper, TypeA>() {
    @Override
    public TypeA map(TypeWrapper value) throws Exception {
        return value.firstType;
    }
});

DataStream<TypeB> streamB = stream1.filter(new FilterFunction<TypeWrapper>() {
    @Override
    public boolean filter(TypeWrapper value) throws Exception {
        return value.secondType != null;
    }
})
.map(new MapFunction<TypeWrapper, TypeB>() {
    @Override
    public TypeB map(TypeWrapper value) throws Exception {
        return value.secondType;
    }
});
```

Because `filter()` and `map()` will be chained to `stream1` both are executed on the same thread and the operation is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._

case class Type1(){}
case class Type2(){}


object MultipleOutputJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // Stream of Type1
    val stream1 = env.addSource((sc: SourceFunction.SourceContext[Type1]) => {
      while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000)
        sc.collect(Type1())
      }
    })

    // Mapping from Type1 to Type2
    val stream2 = stream1.map(t1 => Type2())

    // Collect both the original and the derived data
    stream1.print
    stream2.print

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, that I am looking for a Java solution.

Comment: @Jamie Could You please help me out on this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282692/match-based-on-some-property-between-two-data-streams-and-collect-all-based-on-m